# How not apply page margins on the background image in JasperSoft Studio?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have TIBCO Jaspersoft® Studio 6.8.0.
My report has a background image. When I set page margins to i.e 20mm, it's applied to everything on the page(bands and background). I need to apply the margins to everything on the page except for the background so the background covers all the page including margins and the bands start printing after the page margins. Can this be accomplished?

Comment: Nope :), you need no margins and then set x = margin in report

Comment: I didn't get you. Can it be done or not?

Comment: it can't be done as you are asking it, but you can set margin 0 and then move/size the text/image within the report to have margin.. hence if you put the text 20px from border it will have margin 20...

Comment: How to implement that? Do you mean move all bands i.e down? How will I get the bottom margin? Kindly, show me an example of how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: ok, I posted and answer

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you cannot have different margins on different bands.

Since you need the background image to be **without margins** you need to set the margins to 0 and then use as top margin the `pageHeader` band, bottom margin the `pageFooter` band*****. The left and right margin are achieved by moving and sizing text elements.

The x position will be `x=margin` and `width=pageWidth-2xmargin`

Example

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Example" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" isSummaryWithPageHeaderAndFooter="true" uuid="54602a93-638c-4747-847b-30d87b3dc24a">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band height="595" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        </band>
    </background>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="40" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="31" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="20" y="0" width="555" height="30" uuid="b619cb37-3c87-445d-8d23-58a4fe4cbbc8">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Example text in detail band position x=margin, width = page width - 2 x margin]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

***** If you are using summary band, make sure that `isSummaryWithPageHeaderAndFooter="true"`, as in example to get the top and bottom margins also on the summary band.